# Illegal Instruction-Running Cross compiled c code on android

Tags: android, c, cross-compiling

Please I need help on this :(( This problem was posted before but hasn't resolved.
I'm trying to run C code on Android 2.3.3 platform running on emulator.
Here is my code(not even hello world):
test.c

```
void main() { }
```

Cross compiling: arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -static -o test test.c

```
->adb push test /data/local
->./test
```

I got: Illegal Instruction ./test

I also tried compiling with *-march=armv5* but same result.

CPU Information:

```
->adb shell /proc/cpuinfo
```

CPU architecture: 5TEJ

I already got lost searching over the internet for solution.
If anyone has resolve this or have any idea please share.
I highly appreciate your help.

Comment: Please let me know if the problem is clear. I'm a new user. Thanks

Comment: Could retry compiling with `-mtune=arm926ej-s` option?

Comment: You seem to be using the wrong compiler.  Use the ndk toolchain, either via the ndk-build script or by having it generate a stand alone toolchain which incoroprates most of the flags required to build for android.

Comment: Thanks for replying.
@ouah I tried with '-mtune=arm926ej-s' with and without '-march=armv5'. but no luck.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I'll try your approach. I'm actually not very expert in these stuff. I've to compile the C file to be run from adb shell not via JNI. I'll definitely google, but by any chance do you remember any good documentation for that. I appreciate all your help.

Comment: The emulator is not finding the "test" executable. Perhaps it is not in the current directory after the adb push command. From this page http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html, it looks like you might need to type ->adb push test /data/local/test instead.

Comment: At last! I've been able to solve it with the following approach:
http://android-tricks.blogspot.com/2009/02/hello-world-c-program-on-using-android.html

Thanks Allah :-D

I appreciate all your help.