# Cross-compiling step by step to build a simple "hello world" that run into a WM8650 Tablet from Ubuntu 12

Tags: arm, cross-compiling

i'm a programmer that program in windows world. With experience in Delphi, C for microcontrollers (Motorola, AVR, PIC ) and Assembler. Few months ago i begin to walk into the Linux world, working with routers (DIR 600) like an interface between my hardware (we develop embedded systems) and a web-page.

Some weeks later we start to work with tablets (Chineese cheap based on WM8650) and write some bash programs to communicate with our hardware. All fine.

Later i read that Ubuntu have insede a cross-compiler, so i was install the last version 12.04
but when i try to compile a simple "Hello world" if i use simple gcc al fine inside the ubuntu machine, when compile with the arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc and put the program into the tablet and run it this error is displaying:

Segmentation fault

i was read this link : [Cross compiling static C hello world for Android using arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9324772/cross-compiling-static-c-hello-world-for-android-using-arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc)

But can't understand the right answer.

If some one knows a place or doc file to solve the simple job: cross compile a C program that run into my WM8650 tablet will be appreciated.

Best regards.

Comment: Since you have a Delphi backround, you can also use Lazarus CodeTyphon edition with a cross compiler for ARM Linux. Just remember to install it as admin. http://www.pilotlogic.com/codetyphon/help/codetyphon_current_status.htm

Comment: Thanks, but i try to leave Delphi and concentrate my effort in high-level html/javascript and keep low level in C. The Lazarus way is not the way that i'll wish walk. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You may read this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488050/illegal-instruction-running-cross-compiled-c-code-on-android)

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify architecture or cpu like -march=armv5 in front of arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -static [cpu/architecture] files...